# How to append an image at the beginning of an HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using JavaScript.

I have the link below in my HTML page:

[image]

Now I want to append the green dollar sign before the start of the text and not below it. I currently have the code below:

```
var imgElement = document.createElement("img");
imgElement.setAttribute("src",server+"images/dollar-green.png");
anchor.appendChild(imgElement);
```

Comment: use insertBefore for this

Comment: Less direct answer; this might be a case where I'd prefer using a CSS-based solution; assign a class to all similar text regions, and apply left-padding and a background image (your dollar) with no-repeat to that class. Then you don't need to manually add the image each time you add text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe You should try [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.insertBefore). Change last line of Your code to this:

```
anchor.insertBefore(imgElement, anchor.childNodes[0]);
```

and then add CSS code on `<img>` tag:

```
img {
    float: left;
}
```

or

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

or via JavaScript:

```
imgElement.setAttribute('style','float:left;');
```

Comment: Tried but getting this error: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.

Comment: i am adding 
imgElement.setAttribute('style','float:left;');
imgElement.setAttribute('style','padding-right: 6px;');
imgElement.setAttribute('style','padding-top: 6px;');
it still remains on the top

Comment: Because You are overwriting "style" attribute all the time. You should set `style` like this: `imgElement.setAttribute('style','float:left; padding: 6px 6px 0 0;')`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the insertBefore

```
anchor.insertBefore(imgElement);
```

Comment: Tried but getting this error:
Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.

Comment: Tried this, but now it went up , exactly on top of letter "S"

Comment: Oh you want it on the left side? You need to also change the css and to make it display: inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
anchor.insertBefore(imgElement, anchor.childNodes[0])
```

Comment: Tried this, but now it went up , exactly on top of letter "S"

Answer (score 0):

Easy way of doing this is to use the float style attribute on your image

```js
var anchor = document.getElementById('theAnchor');
var imgElement = document.createElement('img');
imgElement.setAttribute('src','http://www.easyicon.net/api/resize_png_new.php?id=139&size=32');
imgElement.setAttribute('style','float:left;');
anchor.appendChild(imgElement);
```

```html
<a id="theAnchor" style="font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;font-size:26px;color:#ff0000;">
Sample Text
</a>
```